# Save a date time variable in yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to save the my `Date` in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Whatever post I have looked on Stack Overflow or Googling I found that they have there final result in string, but I want my final result in variable of `DateTime` type and it should be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
Console.WriteLine(dateString); // here I am getting as what i want in yyyy-mm-dd format
DateTime newdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
Console.WriteLine(newdate); // but here again it chnages to the normal date format.
```

Comment: It's going to be a string.

Comment: A `DateTime` object does not have a *format* per se. You can only format it when you convert it to a string.

Comment: DateTime doesn't *have* a format. If you want a formatted string, you need a formatted string.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(newDate) also converts your DateTime to string, so...

Comment: I want to save my DateTime as `yyyy-mm-dd` its as per the business requirement.

Comment: You can save your DateTime as a `yyyy-mm-dd` string, but you're going to need to save it _as a string_.

Comment: You can save the *string representation* of a DateTime in that format (which you already know how to do) but a DateTime variable has no format

Comment: Acc. your desired format you don't want to store the time portion in the `DateTime`. Then you just need to use the `Date` property as in: `DateTime dateOnly = newdate.Date`.

Comment: What everyone's saying is, you're not understanding at the core what a DateTime object actually is.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah You shoud save it as `DateTime` and then when it is displayed format it to whatever format you need.

Comment: Yes but the data is going on mainframe database and we dont have control over there, so according to proxy class we have to keep the date in that format only.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah If it has to be saved with that format in the database (and I honestly don't see a reason why it should, as all databases have their own structured date-time type), then you must save it as a formatted string, and not as a `DateTime` object.

Comment: @Sandeep: Each database has DateTime structures WITHOUT formatting. Unless that field in the database is a string, which contains a formatted string. So your C# DateTime does not have to be formatted to fit in a datase column UNLESS that column is a string. How are your putting your DateTime value into the database anyway? Which code do you use? Because if you are using an SQL and you store your value inside the SQL-string, then you are still converting your value to a string.

Comment: you are right but you know we dont have access to mainframe database and we have wcf client proxy class, in the comments they have mentioned that save it in yyyy-mm-dd format... I think i have contact them.. will update you

Comment: @MartinMulder : Please post your comment as answer so that I can mark as answer.

Comment: @dcastro : Your answer also veryhelpful Thank you all very much.

Comment: @Sandeep: I cannot. Since your question has been marked as duplicate, people cannot answer it anymore. They can only comment, and that is what I did. Thanks anyway for the gesture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any "format" makes sense only when you're converting your `DateTime` to `String`.

`DateTime` itself has its own internal representation, and it has no "format" you can see or change.

UPDATE

If you want to get only date part not time, you can use `DateTime.Date` property. Also if you don't need time part - you can get current date as `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you'd mention that `DateTime` has a [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter reasonable, thank you. It looks like OP just wanted only date part.

Comment: Note that `.Date` doesn't completely remove the time portion, only gets the date relative to midnight of the given date, and thus conversion formats are still important

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` variables don't have a format - the only way to apply any sort of format to `DateTime` is to convert it to a string. When you pass your `newDate` into `Console.WriteLine`, `Console.Writeline` calls `.ToString()` under the hood, performing the conversion away from where you have access to pass it a format.

Answer (score 1):

yyyy-MM-dd is a String format and NOT a representation of your Date variable. The framework does not store it as a String. So you cannot expect Console.WriteLine(newdate) to output yyyy-MM-dd.

The Date object would be internally represented as a long.